# Python kernel not found by vscode when running docker container

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-remote

I am trying to build a docker image to do debuging of a module that has lots of odd dependencies in vscocde.

I am using the dockerfile below to build the image:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
USER root

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa && \
    apt update -y && apt install -y \
    gdal-bin \
    geotiff-bin \
    git \
    libgdal-dev \
    libgl1 \
    libspatialindex-dev \ 
    wget \
    python-is-python3 \
    pip \
    g++ 

RUN pip install Cython numpy  

RUN git clone https://github.com/jgrss/geowombat.git

RUN pip install -r /geowombat/requirements.txt

RUN  pip install sklearn-xarray  pip-tools rtree ipykernel

RUN python -c "import geowombat as gw"
RUN python -c "import rasterio;from rasterio.crs import CRS; cc = CRS.from_epsg(4326)"
```

When running the image interactively (as my tests suggest) I can successfully run:

```sh
python
```

However when I use vscode remote containers and docker extension to "attach vscode" or use `shift+cntr+p` to run `Remote-Containers: Attach to running container`

I am unable to access python by executing code in an `.py` file and if I try using an `.ipynb` it informs me I need to install a python kernel from 'the marketplace'.

Basically, vscode doesn't seem to have a connection to the default python kernel.

I am new to this, so any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: NOTE: I need to start from the ubuntu:20.04 image (the `python` image doesn't seem to have 20.04 available)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create and update a dockerfile based on the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python)

Comment: unfortunately can't start from `FROM python:3.8-slim` which builds from ubuntu 22.04, I still next 20.04 for the moment.